# Is it safe to allow all port for local IPs in UFW?

Tags: ssh, iptables, ufw

Is it safe to allow all port for local IPs in UFW? I have a port forwarding set up on my router at a custom port for SSH reverse tunnelling to my SBC and it has 2FA on it. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which version of Linux are you using?

Comment: See for yourself: Ask your system what applications are listening on which ports on your system. Then ask your favorite search engine which of those applications are vulnerable. Those are the ports you must protect.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. Thank you! Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for ARM version. @user535733 I have home assistant on one port and ssh on another. Btw only two ports are allowed for external IPs. Sorry if I was not clear before. But I allowed all port access in ufw for a range of local IPs like from 192.168.0.1 to 20. I am using PLEX and pihole services running on the same machine which is the reason for local port access. By doing so does make the system vulnerable to external attacks from WAN??

Comment: Maybe you are asking how ports work? If no application is listening upon a port, then the port is closed (UFW is superfluous). If your router is properly configured and working, there shouldn't be any external attacks from WAN...except upon your forwarded ports. That's why UFW's default is to accept all packets. There are other ways to attack your system besides WAN, of course. Example: Somebody might connect to your LAN. Firewalls are a specific tool that address specific circumstances. My own LANs have quite limited firewall settings to address specific threats (like a compromised Pi).